# Display data that's bigger than the iPhone screen

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I want to put data in a `UIViewController`, and when the user scrolls down, he will see something else. I want to do this in Interface Builder.

It needs to be something like UITableView.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it by using a UIScrollView or UITableView

Comment: you have any tutorial how to do it?

Comment: http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-tutorials/3393-uiscrollview-tutorial.html

Comment: also apple sample code here - http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Scrolling/Introduction/Intro.html

Answer (score 3):

[`UIScrollView`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html) does exactly that.

Here's a [really simple tutorial](http://idevzilla.com/2010/09/16/uiscrollview-a-really-simple-tutorial/).

Answer (score 1):

If you are wondering how to create a UIView in Interface Builder that is "bigger" than the normal screen, you need to adjust the "Simulated Metrics" properties in Interface Builder.  Make sure you set the status bar to "none" and then you can drag to resize the view.  As far as setting it up for scrolling, you should refer to the tutorials in the other answers.